# How can I prevent a user from typing characters in certain positions of a MaskedTextBox?

Tags: c#, maskedtextbox

Let me explain with this example, lets say we had a MaskedTexBox with the following mask `__-__-____` It's a mask for a date in the `mm-dd-yyyy` format.

On the first position only valid month enties would be 0 or 1.

This part I got to work so when the user presses 2 thru 9 it automatically makes the MaskedTextBox = `02-__-____` or `03-__-____` or `04-__-____` ... `09-__-____` etc.

Seeing how that worked I tried moving on to the next position.  The second position the only valid entries would be 1-9 if the first digit is 0 OR 0-2 if the first digit was 1.

But by pressing the first digit in the first position the 2nd position is set correctly.  But if the user backspaces or clicks in the 2nd position and presses let say 0 I want to prevent the user from being able to press 0 if the first position is already contains a 0.  Because currently it would look like this `00-__-____` and that's an invalid month.

In the "day" positions (3rd and 4th) 3rd should only be allowed to enter 0, 1, 2, 3. And in the 4th position allow only certain digits depending on what the 3rd position already has.

Logic for position 4:

- if 3rd is 0 then position 4 can only allow 1-9
- if 3rd is 1 or 2 then position 4 can only allow 0-9
- if 3rd is 3 then position 4 can only allow 0-1

The "year" positions (5th, 6th, 7th, 8th) also has its own logic.  But to prevent this question from being to complicated or confusing as it might already be i will refrain from posting that logic unless someone asks for it.

So basically each position in the MaskedTextBox string has its own logic that it would need to follow.  I have tried the below code but I have not been able to prevent the user from typing in an invalid digit at said positions.  I was starting to wonder if something like this might not be possible, because other examples i have found that prevent users from entering/typing in a character that is not wanted has just 1 IF/ELSE clause and just 1 `e.Handled = false` and 1 `e.Handled = true`.  While mine would require many placed in deep IF/ELSE clauses.

Is this even possible in C# using the KeyPress event?

Code i have tried so far. Excuse the mess as I have been trying many options with no luck. I have not finished the "year" logic in the code below because i wanted to get the month and day portion working first.

```
    private void mtbTest_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        Char pressedKey = e.KeyChar;

        mtbTest.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals;

        int[] formatLengths = { 0 };

        if (Char.IsNumber(pressedKey))
        {
            if (formatLengths.Contains(mtbTest.Text.Length) && Convert.ToInt32(Char.GetNumericValue(pressedKey)) > 1)
            {
                mtbTest.Text = String.Format("{0}0", mtbTest.Text);
            }

            if (mtbTest.Text.Length == 1)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(mtbTest.Text.Substring(0, 1)) == 0)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(Char.GetNumericValue(pressedKey)) > 1)
                    {
                        e.Handled = false;
                    }
                }

                if (Convert.ToInt32(mtbTest.Text.Substring(0, 1)) == 1)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(Char.GetNumericValue(pressedKey)) < 2)
                    {
                        e.Handled = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (mtbTest.Text.Length == 2 && Convert.ToInt32(Char.GetNumericValue(pressedKey)) > 3)
            {
                mtbTest.Text = String.Format("{0}0", mtbTest.Text);
            }

            if (mtbTest.Text.Length == 3)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(mtbTest.Text.Substring(2, 1)) == 0)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(Char.GetNumericValue(pressedKey)) > 0)
                    {
                        e.Handled = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (mtbTest.Text.Length == 4 && Convert.ToInt32(Char.GetNumericValue(pressedKey)) > 1)
            {
                e.Handled = false;
            }

            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        mtbTest.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.IncludePromptAndLiterals;
    }
```

Comment: Any reason you can't use a date picker control?

Comment: It seems like you're trying to implement a calendar control. Have you thought about using the framework's built in calendar? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.calendar.aspx

Comment: Wouldn't that be easier if you the date time picker with your required format; so the date time picker will automatically force the user to pick the correct date? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx

Comment: It seems like it would be easier to let them enter anything, then throw it out in validation.

Comment: Currently i'm testing on a single MaskedTextBox. Once fully working (if it can be) I would implement this inside a datagridview column.  Where the user would be able to copy/paste from excel or be able to enter in the data by hand.  I'm not sure the calendar would allow me to do that, would it?